# How to prove two expressions are equivalent using formal proofs?

Tags: logic, formal-proofs

I have this argument I'm trying to prove:

```
¬(A ∨ B)
_
¬A ∧ ¬B
```

We have two expressions which are equivalent to eachother. I know they are because they have the same truth values if you put both into a truth table. For formal proofs the rules I know are:

```
∧ Intro
∧ Elim
∨ Intro
∨ Elim
¬ Intro
¬ Elim
⊥ Intro
⊥ Elim
```

So I have to use those rules to prove this argument. From what I can see, there's nothing I can do with the premise because the main connective is the negation and I can't do anything with a single negation therefore the only rule I can start out with is ∧ Intro. The only problem is that I have no idea what to do next or if I'm even using the correct rule.

The thing is, I can formally prove this if it was the other way around:

```
¬A ∧ ¬B
_
¬(A ∨ B)
```

I just use ¬Intro on the bottom and then ∨ Elim and ∧ Elim proving that both A and B will lead to a contradiction. I'm just having problems proving it the other way around.

Comment: If truth tables are the same, the expressions are equivalent, formal proof is not possible without using rules of logic and some of those rules are proven using truth tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start by assuming $A$, then introduce the $\lor$ obtaining $A\lor B$ so, using the hypothesis $\lnot(A\lor B)$, you get $\bot$, so you can discard the assumption $A$ and derive $\lnot A$.
Do the same for $B$ and get $\lnot B$. So you got $\lnot A\land\lnot B$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof using natural deduction in a Fitch-style proof checker. One additional rule I used was biconditional introduction at the end to show the equivalence.

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/